# Would this headset work with Ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility, headset

[This one](http://www.rosewill.com/products/1964/ProductDetail_Overview.htm), by Rosewill. It doesn't mention Ubuntu/Linux compatibility, only Windows. Does anyone know if it works?

Answer (score 2):

Even if it produces sound under Linux, many of the features listed such as "5.1 surround" and "vibration" are not going to work if the company has not released Linux drivers.

Most USB speakers and headphones will work under Ubuntu using generic speaker drivers to produce stereo sound.  I was unable to unable to find any reports of users getting these particular headphones to work, or any headphones made by Rosewill for that matter.

After reading a bunch of reviews I recently purchased Plantronics Gamecom headset.  The surround sound doesn't work, but the stereo audio, volume up and down, mute button, and microphone all do.

With Ubuntu, the functionality of USB headphones leaves a bit to be desired.  Especially for plugging and unplugging them.  When you plug in headphones, Ubuntu does not automatically shut off analog speakers and turn on the headphones.  Each time you plug or unplug, you need to go into the sound setting and specifically choose your input and output sources.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just two questions: would the mic still work? And do you know if there's any surround sound headsets that work properly on Ubuntu? I found <a href="http://alexsleat.co.uk/2011/12/03/setting-up-surround-sound-in-linux/>this tutorial</a> to enable surround sound, but it seems to be fairly generic.

Comment: I didn't find any headphones that had working surround sound drivers.  The mic does work on my headphones.